# Ubuntu doesn't add hard drive to media folder

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

My PC has two hard drives and one SSD.
I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on the SSD, however, I am using one of the hard drives to store my files.

When ever my PC boots into Ubuntu, I can't use the hard drive, until I open it on Files->Other Locations->and then I choose the hard drive folder. And only then the folder appears on /media/

Is there any command I can use to make that happen, other then opening the folder again and again?
Or maybe there is a fix to that problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What file system is there in the partition you want to mount?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.  Create a folder in the `/media` folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/extra_drive
```

Then get your `UUID` of the drive to be mounted:

```
sudo blkid
```

Take note of the `UUID=` like `UUID="98b0a711-18a1-4303-b374-0c8d31bae473"`.  Also, take note of the `TYPE=` as this will be used when creating the line used in `/etc/fstab`

Then add an entry to your `/etc/fstab` file with the `UUID=`:

```
UUID=98b0a711-18a1-4303-b374-0c8d31bae473 /media/extra_drive ext4  defaults 0 0
```

Now, every time you boot the computer up that drive should mount at the same point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It actually worked! Thank you very  much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the drive to the /etc/fstab? 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab